# Poder resolver DNS de un virtualhost en un servidor

Tags: servidor, dns, virtualhost

Tengo un servidor con windows donde tengo configurados virtualhost para cada proyecto que tengo (manual que utilize para configurar con xampp https://styde.net/creando-virtual-hosts-con-apache-en-windows-para-wamp-o-xampp/)

desde el mismo servido si coloco en el navegador proyecto.prod me dirige a mi proyecto sin problemas, ahora si me conecto desde mi equipo y configuro C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host para que resuelva el dns y me rediriga a la ip del servidor me carga el proyecto.

también tengo un servidor que resuelve las dns y no tengo conocimiento en como configurar para que desde el equipo local que se coloque la url del proyecto resuelva y rediriga a la ip del servidor sin necesidad de configurar el host en cada equipo

Comment: en las computadores dentro de esa red, tenes configurado como uno de los dns la ip que corresponde con el servdor DNS que comentas que tienen?

Comment: en un equipo local (el mio) configure el archivo host para que resolviera la dns con la ip del servidor

Comment: si tienes un servidor dns, en él debes crear un archivo de zona para tu dominio, en este caso "prod", y luego configurarle un registro "IN A" dentro para que un subdominio, en este caso "proyecto", apunte a la ip del servidor apache por ejemplo "proyecto IN A 10.10.10.10", luego las maquinas que utilicen como uno de los DNS la IP del "servidor DNS" deberían resolverte el dominio sin problemas.